# RSpec not outputting the statements passed to "it"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a Rails 5 api-only app and recently added RSpec to it. Whenever I run `rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb`, it passes but doesn't output the description of the text.

**Here's a sample `user_spec.rb` file:**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "something" do
  it "does something" do
  end
end
```

**Here's the output:**

```
$ rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb 
.

Finished in 0.0029 seconds (files took 2.38 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

I would expect the output to show "`does something`" etc. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour, but you can try

```
rspec <file> --format documentation
```